# MinGW нету функции CryptQueryObject

Tags: c, mingw

Добрый день, пытаюсь скомпилировать программу на Си, в ней пользуется функция `CryptQueryObject`. Я так понимаю она должна быть в `Wincrypt.h`, но ее там нет. Вопрос собственно такой, как быть? Откуда ее подключить?

Comment: а что, собственно у вас, кроме **MinGW** есть?

Comment: MSDN говорит что подключать ее надо из Wincrypt.h, они врать не будут.

Comment: подозреваю, что о том, что ещё lib файл нужно добавить, никто не знает:)

Comment: Ну так я пользуюсь компилятором не от Microsoft

Comment: @Corle, а сама библиотека есть?

Comment: Сама библиотека есть. Я открыл ее заголовочный файл, wincrypt.h, там нету публикации этой функции

Comment: @KoVadim знаем-знаем ;-)

Comment: @Core, да ладно! :D на строке 1251 нет объявления CryptQueryObject???

Comment: @Sublihim нету у меня

Comment: @Corle всмысле написал?

Comment: может кстати версия компилятора устарела

Comment: компилятор тут причем?

Comment: ну я пользуюсь заголовочными файлами и библиотеками который предлогает MinGW

Comment: значит вы не используете Windows SDK?

Comment: @Sublihim нет, не использую

Comment: тогда не стоит удивляться, что вы не нашли объявление функции CryptQueryObject

Comment: И что делать? подключать сторонние библиотеки?

Comment: С каких пор, для программы, которая пишется под Windows - библиотеки из Windows SDK сторонние?

Comment: Они где лежат? в папке с компилятором от Visual Studio ? я ее даже не устанавливал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По всей видимости, у вас устаревшая версия MinGW. Скачайте и установите себе актуальную версию [MinGW-w64](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php), там в заголовочнике `wincrypt.h` есть описание функции `CryptQueryObject` (строка 4438):

```
WINIMPM WINBOOL WINAPI CryptQueryObject (DWORD dwObjectType, const void *pvObject, DWORD dwExpectedContentTypeFlags, DWORD dwExpectedFormatTypeFlags, DWORD dwFlags, DWORD *pdwMsgAndCertEncodingType, DWORD *pdwContentType, DWORD *pdwFormatType, HCERTSTORE *phCertStore, HCRYPTMSG *phMsg, const void **ppvContext);
```

Comment: Можно тогда вопрос...мне какую версию качать надо? в том плане что там есть какие-то seh, siji, еще что-то. Если что на выходе я должен получить приложение которое запускается и на 86 и 64 разрядных системах

Comment: я скачал MinGW-w64 posix siji, установил...выставил в Code::block в настройках компилятора x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe для Си, x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe для плюсов и там дальше по пунктам..в итоге в логе ошибок Code::block пишет: "execution of x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe failed"

Comment: @Corle Я для x64 не собирал проекты, поэтому точно подсказать не могу. По всей видимости, вам надо делать 2 установки MinGW-w64, под каждую платформу (и Windows у вас, естественно, должна быть x64). В Code::Blocks я просто указывал `gcc.exe` и `g++.exe` и путь на подобии `C:\dev\mingw-w64\mingw32`.  Про модель исключений - рекомендуются [DWARF для win32 и SEH для win64](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-windows/2015q3/000020.html). Подробнее можно посмотреть ещё вот тут: http://wiki.qt.io/MinGW-64-bit

Comment: @Corle А может я не так вас понял и вам не нужен 64-х битный бинарник? Если вы скомпилируете приложение как 32-х битное, то оно будет отлично запускаться и на x64 и на x86. В таком случае, вам при установке MinGW надо выбирать платформу i686, исключения DWARF и потоки win32/posix на выбор.

Comment: да, мне нужна версия х86 что бы на 2х платформах работала программа